# AWS EMR BOTO3 ,could not able to find list of clusters : Need All clusters details

Tags: boto3, amazon-emr

When I want to get list of EMR using boto 3 could not able to get

I tried in different ways

```
  m="None"
  while True:
       try:

         cluster_list_result=client.list_clusters(ClusterStates=['WAITING'], CreatedAfter=datetime(2017,5,19), 
         CreatedBefore=datetime(2019,5,19) ,Marker=m)
         print(cluster_list_result)
         m=cluster_list_result.Marker  # See if there are more



         print("m value is" +m)
       except AttributeError:
        break
```

Need list of cliuster detils

Comment: Invalid type for parameter Marker, value: None, type: <type 'NoneType'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>

Comment: @jaferrando any help

Comment: @omuthu any help

Answer (score 1):

The list_client api of boto3-emr doesn't expects Marker parameter as None. Also it is not necessary that you will always get the Marker parameter back in response as it is just a pagination token for further results.

I have updated your code a bit and this works fine for me :

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('emr',region_name='us-east-1')
marker=None

while True:
    try:
        if marker:
            cluster_list_result=client.list_clusters(ClusterStates=['WAITING'], CreatedAfter=datetime(2017,5,19), CreatedBefore=datetime(2019,5,19), Marker=marker)
        else:
            cluster_list_result = client.list_clusters(ClusterStates=['WAITING'], CreatedAfter=datetime(2017, 5, 19), CreatedBefore=datetime(2019, 5, 19))

        print cluster_list_result

        if 'Marker' in cluster_list_result:
            marker = cluster_list_result['Marker']
        else:
            break
    except Exception, e:
        raise e
```